# macOS iostream on a pseudo tty does not work

Tags: c++, macos-big-sur

GCC has a `stdio_filebuf` extension that lets you wrap an iostream around a file descriptor while clang's `basic_filebuf` has an `__open()` method that lets open a file descriptor. I've tested both on regular files on both linux and macos. Works as expected.

However, for a pseudo tty file descriptor, it works for linux but not macos. I've confirmed that the file descriptor on macos does work by using read(2) on it. Here's my code.

```
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#if defined(__linux__)
#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
#include <fstream>
#else
#error "unsupported os"
#endif
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int get_ptym(int oflags)
{
    int fd;

    if ((fd = posix_openpt(oflags)) == -1
            or grantpt(fd) == -1
            or unlockpt(fd) == -1)
        return -1;
    return fd;
}

ssize_t getdelim(int fd, char *buf, size_t bufsz,
        char delim='\n', bool store_delim=false)
{
    size_t j = 0;
    while (j < bufsz-2) {
        char c;
        ssize_t rc;
        if ((rc = ::read(fd, &c, 1)) == -1) return rc;
        if (rc == 0) break;
        if (c != delim) { buf[j++] = c; continue; }

        // Break if we get the delimiter.
        if (store_delim) buf[j++] = c;
        break;
    }
    buf[j] = '\0';
    return j+1;
}

std::string m0(int fd)
{
#if defined(__linux__)
    __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char> fb(fd, std::ios::in|std::ios::out);
    std::iostream ioob(&fb);
#endif
#if defined(__APPLE__)
    std::basic_filebuf<char> fb;
    std::iostream ioob(fb.__open(fd, std::ios::in|std::ios::out));
#endif

    std::string s;
    if (!std::getline(ioob, s, '\n').good())
        throw std::runtime_error("m0: getline failed");
    return s;
}

std::string m1(int fd)
{
    char buf[4096];
    ssize_t nrd;

    if ((nrd = getdelim(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) == -1)
        throw std::runtime_error("getlim error");

    return std::string(buf);
}

void testing(const std::string &foonm, std::function<std::string(int)> foo)
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    int mfd, sfd;

    // Open pty master and slave.
    if ((mfd = get_ptym(O_RDWR)) == -1) return;
    if ((sfd = open(ptsname(mfd), O_RDWR)) == -1) return;

#if defined(__linux__)
    __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char> fb(sfd, std::ios::in|std::ios::out);
    std::iostream ioob(&fb);
#endif
#if defined(__APPLE__)
    std::basic_filebuf<char> fb;
    std::iostream ioob(fb.__open(sfd, std::ios::in|std::ios::out));
#endif

    fmt::print("testing {}\n", foonm);
    std::string s;
    if (!std::getline(std::cin, s, '\n').good()) {
        fmt::print("{}: getline failed\n", __func__);
        return;
    }

    auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, foo, mfd);
    ioob << s << '\n';
    ioob.flush();

    try {
        std::string fget;
        std::future_status fstatus;
        fstatus = f.wait_for(8s);
        switch (fstatus) {
            case std::future_status::timeout:
                fmt::print("{}: f.wait_for(8s) timed out\n", __func__);
                break;
            case std::future_status::ready:
                fget = f.get();
                fmt::print("{}: fstatus ready, f.get={}\n", __func__, fget);
                break;
            default:
                fmt::print("{}: fstatus default??\n", __func__);
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        fmt::print("{}: exception \"{}\"\n", __func__, e.what());
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    testing("m1", m1);
    testing("m0", m0);
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?